# AWS - Connection timing out on an EC2 Load balancer configured to port 443 with an SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have tried everything to get this to connect with HTTPS. I have added the SSL certificate to my IAM console, added the security group needed to open port 443 and attached it to my load balancer, and have added the HTTPS listener to my load balancer.

Still, I am getting a timeout when going to the HTTPS URL. The HTTP port is open and connects without issue.

I honestly don't know what information might be needed here, as this is my first go at setting up an HTTPS connection on an EC2 instance. Below are some screenshots of how things are set up in the EC2 console:

Load balancer listeners:

[image]

Load balancer port configuration:
[image]

And finally the Security Groups:

[image]
[image]

I realize these may not be the right details, and I cringe at the screenshots, but I am a one-man-band tasked to set this up, and I have no one to turn to for help! Thank you in advance for reading this and any insight provided.

Comment: Is that the security group assigned to the EC2 server(s) or the load balancer? Please show both security groups. Also, is this a classic Load Balancer, Application Load Balancer, or Network Load Balancer?

Comment: Thanks for responding @MarkB. The load balancer is a classic load balancer and that security group is assigned to the load balancer.

Comment: Please add details of the EC2 server security group. And is that IP address in the Load balancer's security group your actual public IP address on the computer the web browser is running in?

Comment: @MarkB I have added the other Security Group to the OP. It should be but I will double check it. It was auto-filled I am pretty sure when I setup the security group.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work.

In the load balancer listener, I had an HTTP and HTTPS listener configured as so:

```
Load Balancer Protocol: HTTP | Load Balancer Port: 80 | Instance Port: 80
Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS | Load Balancer Port: 443 | Instance Port: 80 | SSL Cert
```

The HTTPS listener was timing out no matter what I did. I even edited the security group to allow connections to port 443.

What I ended up doing was changing the HTTPS listener to this:

Load Balancer Protocol: SSL | Instance Protocol: TCP | Load Balancer Port: 443 | Instance Port: 80

And now I can connect to the HTTPS url. I have no idea why this works, but it does and it's good enough for me.